# Invalid CSS in Sass

Tags: css, sass

Whenever I try to compile Sass code to CSS with either the terminal or the program Koala I get this error message:

```
Error: Invalid CSS after "body ": expected selector, was "{" 
       on line 5 of style.sass
  Use --trace for backtrace
```

Here's the piece of code the error seems to be referring to:

```
body {
  background {
    color: $background-color
  }
}
```

How can I fix my code to make it compile correctly?

Comment: you have to remove the curly braces `{}`

Comment: I think your error is caused by something further up. Your compiler may not have realized a problem until it hit the point it mentioned. That said, even if your SASS worked, I don't think it'll do what you expect. `background` is unlikely to be an element but you appear to be treating it as such. I suspect you want `body { background-color: $background-color }` instead.

Comment: @QoP this solved the problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The way your selector reads is that it is looking for the `<body>` element, and then a `<background>` element (which isn't a thing that exists in HTML, to my knowledge), and then you are setting the text inside that element to the `color` in your var `$background-color`.  I think either one of two things:

Either you meant for `background` to be a class or id, like `.background`, in which case your code becomes:

```
body {
  .background {
    color: $background-color;
  }
}
```

Or, more likely, you are very tired and just got your wires crossed, and mean to be setting the `background-color` property like this:

```
body {
  background-color: $background-color;
}
```

Please note that you were also missing an ending semi-colon, which I added.

Answer (score 0):

You cloud try adding a colon after `background`.

```
body {
  background: {
    color: $background-color;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sass, unlike Scss, uses indentation instead of curly braces.

```
body {
    background {
        color: $background-color;
    }
}
```

becomes

```
body
    background
        color: $background-color
```

Though, I'm quite sure you mean to have `background` as a property instead of a selector.

```
body
    background-color: $background-color
```

Answer (score 0):

background must be class name or id or simply background css property.

```
body {
  .background {
    color: $background-color;
  }
}

body {
  #background {
    color: $background-color;
  }
}

body {
  background : $background-color;
}
```